# Backup and restore the local database

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite

while using append mode the running process is completed but the data can't display, using append mode only

Backup method

```
public void backup(String outFileName, boolean appendMode) {
        try {
            File dbFile = new File(mContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).toString());
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);

            // Open the output stream to the backup file
            OutputStream output;
            if (appendMode) {
                output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName, true); // Append mode
                //output.seek(output.length()); // Move cursor to end of file for append mode
            } else {
                output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName, false); // Overwrite mode
            }

            // Transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            // Close the streams
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            fis.close();

            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Backup Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Unable to backup database. Retry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

import method

```
 public void importDB(String inFileName, boolean appendMode) {
        final String outFileName = mContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).toString();

        try {
            File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);

            // Open the output stream to the existing database file
            OutputStream output;
            if (appendMode) {
                output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName, true); // Append mode
            } else {
                // Open the output stream with the read-write flag and create if necessary
                output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName, false); // Overwrite mode
            }

            // Transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            // Close the streams
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            fis.close();

            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Import Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Unable to import database. Retry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

PerformBackup method

```
public void performBackup(final DBHelper db, final String outFileName, boolean appendMode) {
        Permissions.verifyStoragePermissions(activity);

        if (outFileName == null || outFileName.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Invalid backup file name. Please enter a valid file name.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/DewtreatDB");

        boolean success = true;
        if (!folder.exists())
            success = folder.mkdirs();
        if (success) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            builder.setTitle("Backup Name");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Save", (dialog, which) -> {
                String m_Text = "dewtreat";
                String out = outFileName + m_Text + ".db";
                db.backup(out, appendMode); // Call backup() with appendMode
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, which) -> dialog.cancel());

            builder.show();
        } else
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Unable to create directory. Retry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

PerformRestore method

```
 public void performRestore(final DBHelper db, final boolean appendMode) {
        Permissions.verifyStoragePermissions(activity);

        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/DewtreatDB");
        if (folder.exists()) {
            final File[] files = folder.listFiles();
            final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(activity, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item);
            if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
                for (File file : files) {
                    arrayAdapter.add(file.getName());
                }
            }

            AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            builderSingle.setTitle("Restore:");
            builderSingle.setNegativeButton(
                    "cancel",
                    (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());
            builderSingle.setAdapter(
                    arrayAdapter,
                    (dialog, which) -> {
                        SQLiteDatabase database = db.getWritableDatabase();
                        database.beginTransaction();
                        try {
                            db.importDB(files[which].getPath(), appendMode);
                            database.setTransactionSuccessful();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "Unable to restore. Retry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            // End the transaction
                            database.endTransaction();
                        }
                    });
            builderSingle.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Backup folder not present.\nDo a backup before a restore!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to to store the data to local database and restore the data from the local database. while the app was uninstall and get re-install to click restore the existing stored must be show and at the same time while importing the existing data and already there have new data also it will merge and show the all the data.

Comment: You pasted a lot of code and left some kind of description that doesn't make a lot of sense (to me at least), but you didn't actually ask a question. Review this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then update your question for clarity if you hope to get help.